# Powershell Invoking commands in Parallel does not work

Tags: powershell

I am trying a very simple PowerShell Parallel example as specified in the [documentation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/).

```
1..5 | ForEach-Object -Parallel { "Hello $_"; sleep 1; } -ThrottleLimit 5
```

But its giving the following error, any help in this regards would be appropriated.

```
ForEach-Object : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\temp\parallel.ps1:2 char:9
+ 1..10 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [ForEach-Object], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

Following is my PowerShell Version information

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.18362.752
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.18362.752
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Answer (score 5):

`ForEach-Object -Parallel` has been introduced in PowerShell 7.0. You are using PowerShell 5.1. That's why it doesn't work.

If you have PowerShell 7.0 installed in parallel (which is possible), call the PS executable directly and execute your script with that.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation shows powershell 7 by default, which could be confusing.

A start-job alternative, but it's multi-process:

```
1..5 | ForEach-Object { start-job { 
  "Hello $args"; sleep 1 } -args $_ } | receive-job -wait -auto
```

You could download threadjob in powershell 5, which is faster than start-job. https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ThreadJob.  It comes with powershell 7.  It works like foreach-object -parallel.

```
1..5 | ForEach-Object { start-threadjob { 
  "Hello $using:_"; sleep 1 } } | receive-job -wait -auto
```

Answer (score 2):

As the previous answers specified, `Foreach-Object -Parallel` is available in PowerShell 7. 
Still if you need to execute commands in parallel, you may try to explore workflows. More details, could be found in PowerShell help: `Get-Help about_Workflows -ShowWindow`.